# How does firefox use proprietory fonts?

Tags: multi-licensing

Visit about:preferences on firefox and search fonts.Almost every font that is listed is proprietory.How does firefox use them though they are open source?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Those fonts aren't part of Firefox. They're your computer's system fonts. There's no rule that says open-source programs can't use proprietary resources that happen to be available on the system where they're installed.